# Make the header fix while i scroll in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am using bootstrap table. 

My table is very long (a lot of rows).

I have tried to make my table header fix (when I scroll I will still see the header table).

Is there a simple way that I can implement it in bootstrap table? 

My table:

```
 <BootstrapTable tableBodyClass="table borderless" data={rows} hover={true} options={this.state.options} trClassName={trClassFormat} search={true}>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='0' rowSpan='2' dataSort={true} width="40px" isKey={true} dataField="id" hidden>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='0' rowSpan='2' dataField="name" width="110px" dataSort={true}>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='0' rowSpan='2' dataField="lastName" width="30px" editable={false} dataSort={true} sortFunc={this.sortLastPrice}>Last Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='0' colSpan='3'>A</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='1' dataField="a1" width="20px" editable={false} dataSort={true} sortFunc={this.sortA1} columnClassName={columnClassNameFormat}>A1</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='1' dataField="a2" width="25px" editable={false} dataSort={true} sortFunc={this.sortA2} columnClassName={columnClassNameFormat}>A2</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='1' dataField="a3" width="30px" editable={false} dataSort={true} sortFunc={this.sortA3} columnClassName={columnClassNameFormat}>A3</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='0' colSpan='1'>B</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='1' dataField="b1" width="20px" editable={false} dataSort={true} sortFunc={this.sortB1} columnClassName={columnClassNameFormat}>B1</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='0' colSpan='3'>C</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='1' dataField="c1" width="20px" dataSort={true} sortFunc={this.sortC1}>C1</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='1' dataField="c2" width="25px" dataSort={true} sortFunc={this.sortC2}>C2</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn row='1' dataField="c3" width="30px" dataSort={true} sortFunc={this.sortC3}>C3</TableHeaderColumn>
  </BootstrapTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setting fixed CSS is probably only option. I know link only answers are not good but this will 100% help you if you want to use external library to make it fixed. I'm using sticky.js for everything. Ez to use, download it here: http://stickyjs.com/

PS: It's not mine. Don't take it as advertisement, I just think that library is pretty good and easy to use.